# Error in URL when i sharing the article on Twitter

Tags: php, twitter, share, arabic

when i'm use share from my web to twitter by:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?
   url=http://www.noor-journal.com/{{ $posts->category->slug.'/'.$posts->title }}
   &text={{ $posts->author->name }} يكتب: {{ $posts->title }}
   &{{ url($posts->category->slug.'/'.$posts->title) }}
   &via=NoorJournals"
   class="share-btn twitter"
   target="_blank">
   <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
</a>
```

the tweet send without URL Link because the URL it contains Arabic words and spaces like: [this](http://www.noor-journal.com/%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%81%D8%A9/%D9%84%D9%85%20%D8%A3%D8%B9%D8%AF%20%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%81%D8%A7)
i'm using PHP in Laravel.
Thank you

Comment: Run your URL parameters through `urlencode`.